# Как читать и писать в файл через два файловых дескриптора (не используя функции перемещения указателя)

Tags: c++, c

Задача: пусть есть два файловых дескриптора (потоковых переменных, файловых переменных) in и out. Требуется через out написать несколько чисел, а затем, не перемещая указатель (к примеру с помощью seekg или seekp, так как эти функции неприемлемы по времени), через in считать записанные числа.
Проблема в том, что в c++, как я понял, даже если созданы две файловые переменные, связанные с одним файлом, то внутренний указатель в файле, который перемещается по позициям в файле, все равно один. Е

Comment: "Файловый указатель" привязан к дескриптору. Если файл будет открыт без блокировки, то теоретически так получится (плюс поправка на если не помешает кеш).